# How to know if User has changed it's avatar

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using XMPPFramework for iOS and needs to create an update screen where all the updates about users are shown, such as change in status (Doing it via presence), name and Avatar. I am not storing Avatars anywhere, so if someone changes their avatar, I just get an updated avatar.

What I need is a way so that I can get the notification that the use has indeed changed their avatar to something else.

I tried finding in XEPs and found out that in [XEP-0153](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html) point 3.2, it's mentioned that there is a way using hash to check if the client has a cached copy, if not it downloads the new copy of the data. I am sure XMPPFramework does it automatically. Is there any way to find out if the user happened to change their profile pic?

Comment: Are you using `XMPPvCardAvatarModule`?